# DVI-D output (graphics card) to VGA input (monitor)

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have a graphics card that has DVI-D and HDMI outputs, but I've wanted to do dual monitor, so my first monitor uses the HDMI output of the GPU to the HDMI input of the monitor.

I want to use the DVI-D output of my GPU but my 2nd monitor only supports VGA. Can I use a converter DVI-D to VGA that I see online: picture below

[image]

Comment: I changed the title because I think you “mistyped”.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As long as the DVI-D conenctor on your GPU is female and VGA connector on monitor is male, this adapter on the picture will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that’s possible. However, you need an *active converter*, because a DVI-**D** connector does not natively support VGA like DVI-**I**. Correctly made passive adapters will not physically fit anyway.

The adapter in the picture appears to be an active converter.

Active converters may require additional power (typically taken from USB). Cheaper active converters may only use single-link DVI, limiting them to 1920×1200 60 Hz. VGA doesn’t support much more anyway, so this probably doesn’t matter.